# How to get a .class for a Map<Long, String> in java

Tags: java, collections

I am using the below approach to fetch column data of type **Long** from cassandra :

```
// com.datastax.driver.core.Row;

Set<Long> idSet= new HashSet<>();
idSet= row.getSet("rankids", Long.class);
```

So this is working fine from me.

Now I have column of type =   **Set<Map<Long,String>>**
And I am trying like this :

```
Set<Map<Long,String>> rankSet= new HashSet<>();
rankSet = row.getSet("ranks", Map.class);

rankSet.forEach((final Map rankMap) -> {
    rankMap.forEach((k,v) ->LOGGER.info("Key = " + k + ", Value = " + v));
});
```

But this not working. What I need to do here. How to use the ***.class*** properly here.

**UPDATE**

```
// import com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken;

row.getSet("ranks", new TypeToken<Map<Long, String>>() { });
```

This is not giving any error but it is showing as unstable warning.

Comment: This isn't possible as such, due to type erasure. You need to use something like ParameterizedTypeReference. It's part of Spring. I don't know if something like this exists and is compatible with cassandra.

Comment: @QuentinC `row.getSet("ranks", new TypeToken<Map<Long, String>>() { });` But it is showing as unstable warning. `import com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken;`